# Does Debezium work with Percona Server and/or Percona XtraDB Cluster?

Tags: percona, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, percona-xtradb-cluster

As a "drop in replacement" for MySQL, with I believe the same binlog and replication semantics, I assume anywhere in the Debezium docs it says "mysql" I could replace it with "percona" (or for that matter MariaDB), but I wanted to confirm before I lost a lot of time or ran into unexpected gotchas or bugs.

Comment: Hello, JTLYK I am trying to find out if anyone has any experience of this for you.

Comment: Hello again. I didn't find anyone with direct experience of the Change Data Capture, but according to documentation, Percona Server for MySQL and Percona XtraDB Cluster both can supply a binary log of changes in row format, which is what Debezium requires. However, there is a caveat that Percona can only commit to support and provide fixes for software environments that are 'officially' tested and supported, so if you ran into a problem there'd be no guarantee of support. The Percona software is, though, fully open source.

Answer (score 1):

We haven't tested Debezium against Percona. But if it indeed keeps compatability with MySQL's binlog format, things should work. The best would be to try it out yourself. We'd be happy to learn about any findings you may have (Disclaimer: I'm the Debezium project lead).